# change host name initramfs ALERT! /dev/mapper/guacamole--vg-root does not exist

Tags: boot, grub2, lvm, initramfs, hostname

I have two servers - guacamole and chorizo to be set up with Openstack cloud. I installed ubuntu server on one, then used the linux "dd" to image the disk to build the other, and renamed the server hostname. I have restarted it several times since then, no problem. The file system on both drives is LVM.

Recently I had to swap the host names of the two servers. I renamed chorizo to be guacamole and vice versa. The new guacamole works fine, and I thought the new chorizo worked fine.  I had rebooted both servers several times with no issues.

Recently Openstack controller networking (neutron) was installed on chorizo and the server was rebooted. It stopped at the initramfs prompts with

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problesm:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check root delay
- Check root = (did system wait for right device)
- missing modules (cat proc/modules; ls/dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/guacamole--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell.
```

the file /proc/cmdline has

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/... root=/dev/mapper/guacamole--vg-root ro
```

but /dev/mapper contains the files

```
/dev/mapper/chorizo--vg-root
/dev/mapper/chorizo--vg-swap_1 (or something)
```

I tried to Mount the root filesystem under /root:

> mount /path/to/root/dev /root

Exited the initramfs shell:

> exit

this did not boot the file system

I tried to edit /proc/cmdline to put the correct BOOT_IMAGE (that is chorizo rather than guacamole), but initramfs has NO editor. So i Used

> initramfs> sed -i 's/guacamole/chorizo/g' /proc/cmdline

but the file system is read only. So I plugged chorizo's disk into guacamole and got further with startup. I can start up in some kind of single user mode, which will allow me to enter root password and login as root.

I try editing the /proc/cmdline file from there using vim, but the entire file system is read only.

I booted up from guacamole's original disk with Chorizo's disk plugged into another hotplug port so I could mount both disks
From there I could

```
root@guacamole:~# sudo lshw -C disk
*-disk:1
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=000cfebc
```

I did a

> lvm vgchange -a y

and mounted the disk with

> mount ext3 /dev/whatever /chorizo

Did not work. I went through the instructions to mount at
http://www.linuxwave.info/2007/11/mounting-lvm-disk-using-ubuntu-livecd.html
Guacamole wont mount the disk as it believes it is a duplicate of what is already mounted.

I remember something similar happening previously with OSX I believe. That is changing the host name stuffs up the grub boot loader. 
 I have tried starting up from the Ubuntu install disk and reinstalling the grub boot loader, but navigating the rescue menu system I could not find this option.

Any advice would be welcome.